# Plugin Links to page not working

Tags: plugins

Good day,

has anyone had a issue where they developing a plugin and they have a plugin file with all the relevant files.

I created a plugin where you can create a record and in my plugin, I have a create.php and read.php which will add to the db.php plugin page. The problem is that when I click on the button which has a link to create.php or read.php[image], it brings up a Not Found page but that file is definitely in my plugin. Can anybody help me with this? Should I add my sites link before create.php? How do I get that file to become a page? Am I developing the plugin all wrong??? Please help. I've attached some screenshots.

enter image description here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have relative urls that WP don't understand what to do with them.

Start by reading about module developing and also creating settings page and action through the admin.

For example start by reading https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/

Comment: Read those articles, but still not fully understanding where I'm going wrong and how to fix the issue. Think I'm too new to this and it's too difficult to fix the issue